# Ubuntu 16.04 "Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful"

Tags: networking, sudo

We have done a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64-bit) install on a machine I am using. My account has sudo permission and sudo works ok for me from the command line.

When I launch System Settings > Network from the Gnome desktop, and change the proxy configuration, I am prompted for my password:

> System policy prevents setting proxy settings

My account name is correctly shown. But when I enter my password I see:

> Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful please try again

Why is this failing when I have sudo access?

Comment: Add user to `netdev` group `adduser user netdev`

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the user to `netdev` group:

   ```
   sudo adduser "$USER" netdev
   ```
2. Log out and back in to apply the changes.
3. Reload `dbus`:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/dbus reload
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried your suggestion but the problem remains.

Comment: @DavidA: You need to log out and back in to apply the user group membership change. See my edit to the answer.